# How do i make a counter that smoothly/animates the number change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

I want  to count to 100, smoothly so it has an animation on while doing so exactly like the numbers on the following link

Example:
https://akshatmittal.com/youtube-realtime/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is what they used or it is something very similar. Hopefully, this helps!

http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/